# Estimating the Posterior Predictive in Regression

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, statsmodels, pymc

Say I have a random set of X,Y points:

```
x = np.array(range(0,50))
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=40.0, size=200)
y = map((lambda a: a[0] + a[1]), zip(x,y))
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

Assume that I model `y` as a Gaussian for each value of `x` using **linear regression**, how can I estimate the [posterior predictive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution), i.e. **`p(y|x)`** for each (possible) value of `x`?

Is there a straight way of doing this with `pymc`  or `scikit-learn`?

Comment: Do you know how to do this by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly you can do this using the git version of PyMC (PyMC3) and the glm submodule.
For example

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from pymc import glm 

## Make some data
x = np.array(range(0,50))
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=40.0, size=50)
y = 2*x+y
## plt.scatter(x,y)

data = dict(x=x, y=y)
with pm.Model() as model:
    # specify glm and pass in data. The resulting linear model, its likelihood and 
    # and all its parameters are automatically added to our model.
    pm.glm.glm('y ~ x', data)
    step = pm.NUTS() # Instantiate MCMC sampling algorithm
    trace = pm.sample(2000, step)


##fig = pm.traceplot(trace, lines={'alpha': 1, 'beta': 2, 'sigma': .5});## traces
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x, y, label='data')
glm.plot_posterior_predictive(trace, samples=50, eval=x,
                              label='posterior predictive regression lines')
```

To get something like this [image: posterior predictive]

You should find these blog posts interesting:
[1](http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2013/08/12/bayesian-glms-1/) and [2](http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2013/08/27/bayesian-glms-2/) from where I took the ideas.

**Edit**
For getting the y values for each x try this which I got from digging into the glm source.

```
lm = lambda x, sample: sample['Intercept'] + sample['x'] * x ## linear model
samples=50 ## Choose to be the same as in plot call
trace_det = np.empty([samples, len(x)]) ## initialise
for i, rand_loc in enumerate(np.random.randint(0, len(trace), samples)):
    rand_sample = trace[rand_loc]
    trace_det[i] = lm(x, rand_sample)
y = trace_det.T
y[0]
```

Apologies if it's not the most elegant - hopefully you can follow the logic.

Comment: Thanks! I am specifically interested in getting the samples for `y[0], y[1], ... y[50]` (i.e. a vector of samples for each `y[i]`).   Do you know how I can get that?

Comment: To be clear, for each value of x you would like the 50 y values?

Comment: Yes - That is correct (i.e. I am looking for should effectively be the trace of the deterministic).

Comment: From what I can see, getting the trace of a deterministic has been implemented (see here: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/192) but I don't know how to use it e.g. in this example

Comment: I've made an edit - let me know if that's what you were after.